# Xss behaviour SO api

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api, xss

I have a custom html that pulls the latest SO question via the api:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function insertReply(content) {
                output = document.getElementById('sooutput');
                for (var i = 0; i < content.questions.length; i++) {
                    ques = content.questions[i];                 

                    div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.class = "soquestion"
                    a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/" + ques.question_timeline_url;
                    a.innerHTML = ques.title;
                    div.appendChild(a);
                    innerdiv = document.createElement("div");
                    statstr = "A: " + ques.answer_count + " S: " + ques.score + " U: " + ques.owner.display_name + " UR: " + ques.owner.reputation + " T: " + ques.tags.join(", ");
                    innerdiv.innerHTML = statstr;
                    div.appendChild(innerdiv);
                    output.appendChild(div);
                }

            }

            // create script element
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            // assing src with callback name
            script.src = 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/unanswered?order=desc&tagged=python or nginx or uwsgi or mongodb or pymongo&jsonp=insertReply';
            // insert script to document and load content
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        </script>
```

I noticed something weird on this page:

[image: what does this select dd do here?]

A select dropdown.

The json for that question is:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "python",
    "select",
    "xpath",
    "option"
  ],
  "answer_count": 1,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "question_timeline_url": "/questions/19376327/timeline",
  "question_comments_url": "/questions/19376327/comments",
  "question_answers_url": "/questions/19376327/answers",
  "question_id": 19376327,
  "owner": {
    "user_id": 2742533,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "display_name": "user2742533",
    "reputation": 8,
    "email_hash": "623026bd43fe22b143a1933052ea3c08"
  },
  "creation_date": 1381825105,
  "last_edit_date": 1381825195,
  "last_activity_date": 1381825687,
  "up_vote_count": 0,
  "down_vote_count": 0,
  "view_count": 17,
  "score": 0,
  "community_owned": false,
  "title": "\"Select only works on <select> elements, not on <td>\" error using xpath"
},
```

So I did some test, and it also emits `<script>` tags:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "python"
  ],
  "answer_count": 0,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "question_timeline_url": "/questions/19376455/timeline",
  "question_comments_url": "/questions/19376455/comments",
  "question_answers_url": "/questions/19376455/answers",
  "question_id": 19376455,
  "owner": {
    "user_id": 248922,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "display_name": "RickyA",
    "reputation": 2184,
    "email_hash": "291b4e8cd153dbd24c94776d540876b8"
  },
  "creation_date": 1381825601,
  "last_activity_date": 1381825601,
  "up_vote_count": 0,
  "down_vote_count": 1,
  "view_count": 3,
  "score": -1,
  "community_owned": false,
  "title": "xss test <script>alert(\"bla\");</script>?"
},
```

The key question is if this intended by design. Should the consumer of the api encode all dangerous characters or should the api return the (html) encoded string here?

Comment: I'd say the mistake is yours: you're treating arbitrary text as html.

Comment: Well thats fine. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't a design flaw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Version 1.x of the API put the burden of proper encoding on the consumer for certain fields, so this behaviour is by design and just something that developers had to be careful of.

However, because that wasn't the most consumer-friendly design, the [current version of the API](https://api.stackexchange.com) (which it is recommended that you use) introduces the notion of [field safety](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters). By default this involves properly encoding fields [like the title from your example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=19376327&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: Whow, completely missed 2.x versions. Stupid Google still points to 1.x. Nice to see you have this already tackled. Thanks!